# Resources to learn Ajax with Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any good resources to learn Ajax(jQuery) with Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Railscast is a good resource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)

But really, jQuery AJAX is what it is regardless of your framework. You can always have a click event fire an AJAX call to your controller, have your controller return a JSON object, and have a success handler that keys off of properties from this object to update the DOM. The main difference with Rails is that you can send back a js.erb template instead, which can execute some JavaScript as well as render some partials.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just learning Rails 3 and finding [this](http://railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) tutorial very useful

Chapter 12.2.5 (it is now in 11.2.5) has a bit on Ajax

Answer (score 1):

[Rails 3 Remote Links and Forms](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/)

[Exploring jQuery](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/exploring-jquery-live-and-die/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a video of JS you can reuse.  http://www.ror-e.com/info/videos/3  If you learn via videos you might like it.